# How to delete QTreeWidgetItem's children

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

The code creates a single dialog with QTreeWidget and a button. When the button is clicked I want to delete all the children of the Root item that is currently selected. How to achieve it?

[image]

```
app = QApplication([])        
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(['Column name'])
        for i in range(3):
            root_item = QTreeWidgetItem()
            root_item.setText(0, 'Root %s' % i)
            self.tree.addTopLevelItem(root_item)
            for n in range(3):
                childItem = QTreeWidgetItem(root_item)
                childItem.setText(0, 'Child %s' % n)
            root_item.setExpanded(True)

        btn = QPushButton(self)
        btn.setText("Delete the selected Root item's child items")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.tree)
        self.layout().addWidget(btn)
        self.show()

    def onClick(self):
        current_item = self.tree.currentItem()
        if not current_item:
            print 'Please select root item fist'
        elif current_item.parent():
            print 'Child item is selected. Please select root item instead.'
        else:
            print 'Root item selected. Number of children: %r' % current_item.childCount()    

tree = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: The image you are showing is a bit confusing since you have selected an item that does not have children, I assume that you want when you select an item that has children, only your children are deleted. I am right?

Comment: The root item must be selected in order to delete its children items. If the child item is selected nothing would happen: it just prints the notice that the user must select a root item.

Comment: When I select *Root 0* I get the following message *Please select root item fist*

Comment: With the structure you have now, never enter the **else**

Comment: The topLevel have no parent and in your case the Root X are topLevel.

Comment: Edited it! It was extra `not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
current_item = self.tree.currentItem()
children = []
for child in range(current_item.childCount()):
    children.append(current_item.child(child))
for child in children:
     current_item.removeChild(child)
```